Is there an adb command to force GPU rendering as it is on developer options?
It's for an Android TV that has the developer menu stripped, it's chinese, I figured I can only change those things through ADB. If you know the command to limit background options as well I'd appreciate that a lot as well, just trying to make it smoother!

android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in android manifest will do that

is this system-wide like the setting or app specific?
